# Game Logic and the delay sensor: how to make "delay" a random number

Tags: logic-bricks

This one is self explanitory, I simply want a delay sensor to be a random number between 60 and 120.

Anybody know the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a python script to change the delay to a different random value each time it fires.

```
import bge
import random

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()

sens = cont.sensors['Delay']

sens.delay = random.randint(60,120)
```

Add the script to a text block in blender and connect a python controller to the delay sensor.

[image: Game logic bricks setup]